# Irreducible representations of $D_4$ viewed as a subgroup of $S_4$.

Tags: representation-theory

**Problem:** Let $D_4 = \langle (1234),(24)\rangle \subseteq S_4$.

- Prove that $D_4$ has exactly $3$ non-trivial 1-d characters and that they correspond bijectively to its $3$ subgroups of order $4$ by sending $\chi$ to $\ker \chi$.
- If $\chi$ is such a character and $K$ its kernel, prove that $\text{Ind}_{D_4}^{S_4}\chi$ is an irreducible three dimensional representation of $D_4$ unless $K = V_4$ the Klein four group.
- In the case where $K = V$ find the decomposition of the induced representation.
- Do we get every $3$ dimensional irreducible representation of $S_4$ this way?
- Is every irreducible representation of $S_4$ induced from a one-dimensional character of a subgroup.

*Attempts:*

- For the first issue, I know that the abelianization of $D_4$ is the Klein-four group and so there are four one-dimensional characters, and three non-trivial ones. I know that any of those irreducible characters has a kernel $\ker \chi$, but without being given the character table I wouldn't know how to determine what these kernels are, or the bijection.
- I know that the dimension of the induced representation is always the dimension of where you induce from multiplied by the index of the subgroup, since $[S_4:D_4] = 24/8=3$ it follows that any induced representation is three dimensional. I don't see where this would break if we induced from the one-dimensional character with $V$ as the kernel. Also, I don't know I can argue that the representation is irreducible, I know that its sufficient to have that $\chi^g(h) = \chi(g^{-1}hg)$ is not isomorphic to $\chi$, but again without the character table how can I utilize this?

For the remaining problems I don't know how to start. I imagine that if I could find subgroups with index that didn't build up to characters of the right dimension I could find an irreducible character that wasn't induced, but I don't know how I would do this in general. I would appreciate any tips to get started.

Comment: If you calculated the commutators, you undoubtedly noticed that $H:=[D_4,D_4]=\langle(13)(24)\rangle.$ So the 1-dimensional characters are constants within cosets of $H$, and otherwise "look like the characters of the Klein four". You can read their kernels from that data, each consisting of two cosets of $H$.

Comment: Many of your questions in the second bullet can be decided by constructing the corresponding characters and calculating the inner products. You can try and use Frobenius reciprocity, if that has already been covered, but you still need to calculate at least some values of the induced characters. Hop to it! The copy of the Klein four is special because it is a normal subgroup of $S_4$.